# Как вывести последние записи в рубрике wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Имеется 3 рубрики на wordpress, как вывести по одной последней статье из каждой рубрики?

Answer (score 0):

День добрый!
Код прост, рабочий пример ниже:

```
//Получаем весь список категорий
$categories = get_categories( $args );

//Проходим по всем категориям в цикле
if( $categories )
{
    foreach( $categories as $cat )
    {
        //Получаем ID категории
        $cat->term_id;      

        // параметры для выбора постов
        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => 1, //количество постов для выборки
            'category'    => $cat, //id категории для выборки
            'orderby'     => 'date',
            'order'       => 'DESC',
            'include'     => array(),
            'exclude'     => array(),
            'meta_key'    => '',
            'meta_value'  =>'',
            'post_type'   => 'post',
            'suppress_filters' => true, // подавление работы фильтров изменения SQL запроса
        );

        //получаем посты категории
        $posts = get_posts( $args );

        //выводим посты в цикле (в нашем случае только один)
        foreach($posts as $post)
        { 
            setup_postdata($post);
            // формат вывода
        }
        wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс
    }
}
```

Ссылки на документацию:

[get_categories()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_categories)

[get_posts()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts)